# Example of the Object Calisthenics First Class Collection rule in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I am playing with the Object Calisthenics rules and I am having some troubles to see when to use the first class collections when using C#.

I mean I hardly see when it's supposed to be used, for example it would be hard to apply that rule to an EF `DbContext`.

Let's say, we design a Board class.

```
public class Board
{
    public IList<BoardRow> Rows { get; }
    public IList<BoardColumn> Columns { get; }

    public Board()
    {
        Rows = new List<BoardRow>();
        Columns = new List<BoardColumn>();
    }
}
```

So according to that rule, we would have to turn the code above into:

```
// Is it really that better than just using List<BoardRow>?
public class BoardRowCollection : IEnumerable<BoardRow>
{
    public void Add(BoardRow row) { /*...*/ }
    public void Remove(BoardRow row) { /*...*/ }

    // IEnumerable<BoardRow> Impl goes here...
}

// Is it really that better than just using List<BoardColumn>?
public class BoardColumnCollection : IEnumerable<BoardColumn>
{
    public void Add(BoardColumn column) { /*...*/ }
    public void Remove(BoardColumn column) { /*...*/ }

    // IEnumerable<BoardRow> Impl goes here...
}

public class Board
{
    public BoardRowCollection Rows { get; }
    public BoardColumnCollection Column { get; }

    // Rest of the impl, ctor, etc.
}
```

I am not really sure to get the point of this rule when you already have base classes that can be leveraged to achieve your goals.

Maybe the code above is not the best but I would like to see one example which can shed the light on the purpose of that rule.

Comment: For me, it's just a sort of a "guideline". Sometimes this might be good (but I'm skeptical about it), sometimes not at all. It depends on a practical use case. In general, these rules look suspicious for me. "Don't use the `else` keyword"? "No properties"? I wouldn't trust such a guideline. Anyway, it's heavily opinion based.

Comment: @dymanoid I can get the no properties rule to some extent or the don't use the else keyword, it can help to enforce real OO coding. But this property things except for heavy domain types (like value objects / aggregates in DDD).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Background

Assume you have a class `Foo` and for any reason it needs `Rows` from `Board`.

Now `Foo` needs to find the 5th item in `Rows`. Some days later you need a class `Buu` and it should find the 8th item in `Rows`.

Both `Foo` and `Buu` have its own implementation on how to find an item in `Rows`.

```
// ...
Foo foo = new Foo(board.getRows());
Buu buu = new Buu(foo.getRows());

BoardRow row5 = foo.find5thRow();
BoardRow row8 = buu.find8thRow();
```

## Only a Collection itself should know how to do operations on it

From the [Objects Calisthenics](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/luontola/tdd-2009/ext/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf):

> Application of this rule is simple: any class that contains a collection should contain no other
>   member variables.   Each collection gets wrapped in its own class, so now behaviors related to
>   the collection have a home.  You may find that filters become a part of this new class.   Also,
>   your new class can handle activities like joining two groups together or applying a rule to each
>   element of the group.

If we would create an First Class Collection for Rows we could pass an instance of it to `Foo` and `Boo` and call a method on it:

```
class Foo {
    RowCollection rowCollection;

    // constructor and more ...

    public BoardRow find5thRow() {
        rowCollection.findByIndex(5);
    }
}
```

## Summary

A First Class Collection should cover operations like create, read, update, delete, filtering, merging and more. Pass an instance of a First Class Collection instead of the collection it self. The advantage is that you only have to delegate methods to your First Class Collection instead of writing a new copy of an operation.